# Angular format for numeric textbox

Tags: angularjs-directive

I need to format the value of a textbox to either currency or percentage. The problem is I am new to angularjs and I can't find an immediate answer in google. I hope you can help me with this.

This is the code snippet for razor view:

> ClientPlace
>
> check if Rate || uncheck if Dollar value

this is for the angular part:

> $scope.SelectPlacement = function () {
>           if ($scope.formData.cbClientPlacement) {
>               {
>                   {
>                       $scope.formData.txtClientPlacement.kendoNumericTextBox.kendoNumericTextBox({
>                           format: 'p0',
>                           decimals: 4,
>                           min: 0,
>                           max: 1,
>                           step: 0.01,
>                       });
>                   }
>               }
>           } else {
>
> ```
>         {{ $scope.formData.txtClientPlacement.kendoNumericTextBox({  decimal:2
> ```
>
> }); }}
>           }
>       };

the idea is just to display the format in either Percentage or Dollar value depends on a checkbox click event. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to my question. Below are the code snippets:

```
$scope.SelectPlacement = function () {
        if ($scope.formData.cbClientPlacement) {
            $("#txtCP").kendoNumericTextBox({
                format: "{0:p}",
                decimals: 4,
                min: 0,
                max: 1,
                step: 0.01
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#txtCP").kendoNumericTextBox({
                format: "{0:c}",
                decimals: 2
            });
        }
    };
```